# Managing gradle plugin version with BOM

Tags: gradle, plugins, dependency-management, maven-bom

I'm about to add `io.freefair.lombok` plugin to my gradle projects.

```
plugins {
    id "io.freefair.lombok" version "5.3.3.3"
}
```

Problem is, I have to add this script more than 20+ repositories.
If I have to upgrade plugin version within this scenario, every single `build.gradle` should be modified and it doesn't seem to be a good solution.

I wonder if I can manage plugin version with BOM.
Or any other possible solution would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

If you use Gradle 6.9+ or 7.0+, you could use [dynamic versions](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dynamic_versions.html#sub:declaring_dependency_with_dynamic_version), such as `latest.release` or `5.+` ([Declaring Versions and Ranges](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/single_versions.html)).

```
plugins {
    id "io.freefair.lombok" version "5.3.+"
}
```

Please be aware that `io.freefair.lombok` plugin versions are usually tied to specific Gradle versions. Should you use the Gradle Wrapper, using `latest.release` without upgrading Gradle may break your builds.

This approach could be combined with a custom Gradle plugin or [init script](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/init_scripts.html). For example, you could have a custom plugin that depends on a curated list of maintained plugins required for your builds. When your plugin gets applied, it should be able to apply other plugins as well.

```
plugins {
    id "com.company.my-gradle-plugin" version "latest.release"
}
```

Comment: Does this solution solves my fundamental concern?What I want to implement is managing gradle plugin version across lots of repositories.

Comment: @Helloworld The question I'm asking myself is how you would do it in Maven (I'm not a Maven expert :-) ). Of course, you can have a parent POM, or import a BOM but this wouldn't solve the problem of touching all build files on plugin updates. My answer sketches a potential solution of what I'm thinking may solve the problem of touching all `build.gradle` files.

Comment: Understood. I also agree with you. Thanks for the answer ;-)